# left join messing the query up

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, left-join

I'm having some troubles with this query, its not returning all rows as it should be:

```
SELECT DE.user_id, 
       DE.id, 
       DE.title, 
       DE.limit_new_cards, 
       DE.limit_old_cards, 
       DE.deleted, 
       Count(DISTINCT TCA.id) total_cards, 
       Count(DISTINCT NCA.id) new_cards, 
       Count(DISTINCT OCA.id) due_cards 
FROM   decks AS DE 
       LEFT JOIN cards AS TCA 
              ON TCA.deck_id = DE.id 
       LEFT JOIN cards AS NCA 
              ON NCA.deck_id = DE.id 
                 AND NCA.is_new = 1 
       LEFT JOIN cards AS OCA 
              ON OCA.deck_id = DE.id 
                 AND OCA.due_date <= CURRENT_DATE() 
WHERE  DE.user_id = 47 
GROUP  BY TCA.deck_id 
ORDER  BY DE.id;
```

Should it return the same number of rows as this query does? or not?

```
SELECT user_id, 
       id, 
       title, 
       limit_new_cards, 
       limit_old_cards, 
       deleted, 
FROM   decks 
WHERE  user_id = 47 
ORDER  BY id;
```

I'd be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY TCA.deck_id
```

Should be:

```
GROUP BY DE.id
```

Rationale: `TCA` is a `LEFT JOIN`ed table that has the following condition:

```
ON TCA.deck_id = DE.id
```

When there is no match in `TCA`, `TCA.deck_id` is `NULL`, which you then `GROUP BY`. So you end up with all `DE.id`s that have no match in `TCA` grouped together. Instead you should use the corresponding column from base table `DE` - which, presumably, is never `NULL`.